# How to resolve "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" while running jest test case

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, jestjs, babeljs

I am a beginner `reactjs` developer and building code editor using `monaco-editor` library in my react typescript. I have integrated the `monaco` editor and web worker in my project.
I have created project using `CRA` and using `webpack 5`.

I am trying to write a test case using jest library, but I am stuck with the error which is:

`"SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"`

I tried to add some configuration in jest.config.js and babel.config.js.

`jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "babel-jest",
    "node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/css/css.worker": "babel-jest",
  },
  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json",
      useESM: true 
    },
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    // Use the mock for Worker creation
    // 'worker-loader!.*': 'src/__mocks__/workerMock.js',
    "monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/(.*)/(.*).worker":
      `<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/moanco-editor-mock.ts`,
  },
  // setupFiles: [`${__dirname}/jest.setup.js`],
  testEnvironment: "node",  
  modulePaths: ['<rootDir>/node_modules'],
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules'],
};
```

`babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-typescript"],
  plugins: ["transform-import-meta"],
};
```

The error is related to monaco editor import which is taking place in my `MonacoEditor.tsx` component. This components create the editor in useEffect and call the `MonacoEnvironment.tsx`

There might be some mistake in my implementation and I will appreciate any solution on my implementation.

Here is my `MonacoEditor.tsx`

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import * as monaco from "monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api";
// import * as ts from "monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/typescript/ts.worker.js";
import "../../../styles/MonacoEditor.css";
import MonacoEnvironment from "./editor.worker";


const MonacoEditor: React.FC = () => {
  const editorContainer = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const editorRef = useRef<monaco.editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor | null>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const createEditor = async () => {
      if (editorContainer.current) {
        const editor = monaco.editor.create(editorContainer.current, {
          value: "",
          language: "typescript",
          theme: "vs-dark",
          minimap: { enabled: true },
          automaticLayout: true,
        });

        editorRef.current = editor;
        MonacoEnvironment(); 

        window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
          // Trigger Monaco Editor's automatic layout adjustment on window resize
          editor.layout();
        });
        return () =>
          window.removeEventListener("resize", () => editor.layout());
      }
    };
    createEditor();
    // Cleanup function
    return () => {
      if (editorRef.current) {
        editorRef.current.dispose();
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="Monaco_Editor_Outer_Wrapper">
      <div ref={editorContainer} className="Monaco_Editor_Main_Container1" />
    </div>
  );
};
export default MonacoEditor;
```

Here is my MonacoEnviroment.tsx which is called inside useEffect and create the web worker to above freezing UI.

`MonacoEnviroment.tsx`

```
import React from "react";

const MonacoEnvironment = () => {
  console.log("MonacoEnvironment");
  window.MonacoEnvironment = {
    getWorker(moduleId: string, label: string) {
      switch (label) {
        case "css":
        case "less":
        case "scss":
          return new Worker(
            new URL(
              "monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/css/css.worker",
              import.meta.url
            )
          );
        case "editorWorkerService":
          return new Worker(
            new URL(
              "monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.worker",
              import.meta.url
            )
          );
        case "handlebars":
        case "html":
        // return new Worker(new URL("monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/html/html.worker" ,  import.meta.url) )
        case "razor":
          return new Worker(
            new URL(
              "monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/html/html.worker",
              import.meta.url
            )
          );
        case "json":
          return new Worker(
            new URL(
              "monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/json/json.worker",
              import.meta.url
            )
          );
        case "javascript":
        case "typescript":
          return new Worker(
            new URL(
              "monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/typescript/ts.worker",
              import.meta.url
            )
          );
        default:
          throw new Error(`Unknown label ${label}`);
      }
    },
  };
};

export default MonacoEnvironment;
```

The test case which I have wrote for the MonacoEditor.tsx to test the component.

`MonacoEditor.test.tsx`

```
// MonacoEditor.test.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import MonacoEditor from '../components/middleComponent/monacoEditor/MonacoEditor';

// Mock MonacoEnvironment module


jest.mock('../components/middleComponent/monacoEditor/editor.worker', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: jest.fn(),
}));


describe('MonacoEditor', () => {
  it('renders successfully', async () => {
    // Render the MonacoEditor component
    render(<MonacoEditor />);

    // Your test code goes here

    // For example, you can assert that MonacoEnvironment was called
    expect(require('../components/middleComponent/monacoEditor/editor.worker').default).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

the error I am facing while running this test case by `npm run test`

```
 src/tests/MonacoEditor.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run
                                                                                                                                                                    
    Jest encountered an unexpected token                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                    
    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                    
    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.                                 
                                                                                                                                                                    
    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Desktop\prometheus_UI\prometheus_dev_codesimple-frontend\node_modules\monaco-editor\esm\vs\editor\editor.api.js:5
    import { EditorOptions } from './common/config/editorOptions.js';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      1 | import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
    > 2 | import * as monaco from "monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api";
        | ^
      3 | // import * as ts from "monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/typescript/ts.worker.js";
      4 | import "../../../styles/MonacoEditor.css";
      5 | import MonacoEnvironment from "./editor.worker";

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/middleComponent/monacoEditor/MonacoEditor.tsx:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/tests/MonacoEditor.test.tsx:4:1)
```

I tried to change the configuration of webpack and jest to support the error but unable to solve it.

here is my `webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require("path");
const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require("monaco-editor-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
  entry: {
    app: "./src/index.tsx",
    "editor.worker": "monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.worker.js",
    "json.worker": "monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/json/json.worker",
    "css.worker": "monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/css/css.worker",
    "html.worker": "monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/html/html.worker",
    "ts.worker": "monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/typescript/ts.worker",
  },
  // output: {
  //   path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  //   filename: "bundle.js",
  // },
  output: {
    globalObject: "self",
    filename: (chunkData) => {
      switch (chunkData.chunk.name) {
        case "editor.worker":
          return "editor.worker.js";
        default:
          return "bundle.[hash].js";
      }
    },
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.ttf$/,
        use: ["file-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx$/,
        use: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.worker\.tsx$/,
        use: { loader: "worker-loader" },
      },
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new MonacoWebpackPlugin({
      languages: ["javascript", "typescript", "css"],
    }),
    "babel-plugin-transform-import-meta",
    { module: "ES6" },
  ],
};
```

Also installed some dependencies like  `"babel-plugin-named-exports-order": "^0.0.2", "babel-plugin-transform-import-meta": "^2.2.1",`

for more information look at my `package.json`

```
{
    "name": "editor-frontend",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
        "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.18",
        "@mui/material": "^5.14.18",
        "@react-spring/web": "^9.7.3",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "@types/node": "^16.18.61",
        "@types/react": "^18.2.37",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.15",
        "monaco-editor-webpack-plugin": "^7.1.0",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-icons": "^4.12.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.20.1",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "typescript": "^4.9.5",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
    },
    
    
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
        "build-storybook": "storybook build"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest",
            "plugin:storybook/recommended"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.23.7",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.7",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.23.3",
        "@jest/globals": "^29.7.0",
        "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.5.3",
        "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.5.3",
        "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.5.3",
        "@storybook/addon-onboarding": "^1.0.8",
        "@storybook/blocks": "^7.5.3",
        "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^7.5.3",
        "@storybook/react": "^7.5.3",
        "@storybook/react-webpack5": "^7.5.3",
        "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.2.2",
        "@types/jest": "^29.5.10",
        "@types/react-icons": "^3.0.0",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
        "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.7",
        "babel-jest": "^29.7.0",
        "babel-plugin-named-exports-order": "^0.0.2",
        "babel-plugin-transform-import-meta": "^2.2.1",
        "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.15",
        "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
        "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
        "storybook": "^7.5.3",
        "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
        "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
        "webpack": "^5.89.0",
        "worker-loader": "^3.0.8"
    }
}
```

here I am adding my ts.config file for more accurate solution
`ts.config.js`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ], 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Jest still uses the CommonJS moduling system (`const X = require('X')`).

Your error message looks like you provided an EcmaScript module (`import X from 'X'`)

As you use ts-jest to test your TypeScript tests, it would be helpful to also post your `tsconfig.json`, so i can analyze it further.

From the rest i can just get the information that:

```
C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Desktop\prometheus_UI\prometheus_dev_codesimple-frontend\node_modules\monaco-editor\esm\vs\editor\editor.api.js:5
    import { EditorOptions } from './common/config/editorOptions.js';
```

tells us, that the file is not properly converted into CommonJS as `By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.`

Jest already tells us what to do if we want to: `• To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.`

I dont have an example right now, but i always do something like this: `/(?!monaco-editor)`. Basically just telling Jest to ignore the transformation for all node_modules except `monaco-editor`. Works with basic Regex and [negative-lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

If the error message appears again, with a different module, just add the new module to the regex like `/(?!(monaco-editor|<new-module>))`

Maybe the regex syntax is a bit different.

Hope this helps,
Mika

Comment: Hey MGrief, I tried your solution it didn't work for me can you look at it one more time and also I am providing ts.config.js file below so you get more understanding.
Thanks for your solution.